# call of overloaded ‘malloc(int)’ is ambiguous

Tags: c++

The following function belongs to the CoinUtils project, that is used in the open-source CBC linear programming solver.

```
/** Returns strdup or NULL if original NULL */
inline char *CoinStrdup(const char *name)
{
  char *dup = NULL;
  if (name) {
    const int len = static_cast< int >(strlen(name));
    dup = static_cast< char * >(malloc(len + 1));
    CoinMemcpyN(name, len, dup);
    dup[len] = 0;
  }
  return dup;
}
```

I'm getting the following error when I compile in debug mode in GCC 11 under ubuntu 22.04.

```
error: call of overloaded ‘malloc(int)’ is ambiguous
  624 |     dup = static_cast< char * >(malloc(len + 1));
```

**Can someone explain what's going on?**

The complete error message is this:

```
In file included from /src/third_party/coin-or/Clp/src/ClpModel.hpp:21,
                 from /src/third_party/coin-or/Clp/src/ClpSimplex.hpp:16,
                 from /src/engine/core/../core/lp_interface/lp_osi_interface.h:12,
                 from /src/test/lp_tests.h:13,
                 from /src/test/lp_tests.cpp:5:
/src/third_party/coin-or/CoinUtils/src/CoinHelperFunctions.hpp: In function ‘char* CoinStrdup(const char*)’:
/src/third_party/coin-or/CoinUtils/src/CoinHelperFunctions.hpp:624:39: error: call of overloaded ‘malloc(int)’ is ambiguous
  624 |     dup = static_cast< char * >(malloc(len + 1));
      |                                 ~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/c++/11/cstdlib:75,
                 from /usr/include/c++/11/ext/string_conversions.h:41,
                 from /usr/include/c++/11/bits/basic_string.h:6608,
                 from /usr/include/c++/11/string:55,
                 from /usr/include/c++/11/bits/locale_classes.h:40,
                 from /usr/include/c++/11/bits/ios_base.h:41,
                 from /usr/include/c++/11/ios:42,
                 from /usr/include/c++/11/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/11/iostream:39,
                 from /src/test/testing_utilities.h:8,
                 from /src/test/lp_tests.h:8,
                 from /src/test/lp_tests.cpp:5:
/usr/include/stdlib.h:540:14: note: candidate: ‘void* malloc(size_t)’
  540 | extern void *malloc (size_t __size) __THROW __attribute_malloc__
      |              ^~~~~~
In file included from /src/third_party/header_only/armadillo-11.1.0/include/armadillo:134,
                 from /src/test/testing_utilities.h:9,
                 from /src/test/lp_tests.h:8,
                 from /src/test/lp_tests.cpp:5:
/src/third_party/header_only/armadillo-11.1.0/include/armadillo_bits/translate_superlu.hpp:332:3: note: candidate: ‘void* arma::superlu::malloc(std::size_t)’
  332 |   malloc(size_t N)
      |   ^~~~~~
In file included from /src/third_party/coin-or/CoinUtils/src/CoinModel.hpp:8,
                 from /src/engine/core/../core/lp_interface/lp_osi_interface.h:16,
                 from /src/test/lp_tests.h:13,
                 from /src/test/lp_tests.cpp:5:
/src/third_party/coin-or/CoinUtils/src/CoinModelUseful.hpp: In destructor ‘CoinYacc::~CoinYacc()’:
/src/third_party/coin-or/CoinUtils/src/CoinModelUseful.hpp:200:11: error: call of overloaded ‘free(char*&)’ is ambiguous
  200 |       free(symbuf);
      |       ~~~~^~~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/c++/11/cstdlib:75,
                 from /usr/include/c++/11/ext/string_conversions.h:41,
                 from /usr/include/c++/11/bits/basic_string.h:6608,
                 from /usr/include/c++/11/string:55,
                 from /usr/include/c++/11/bits/locale_classes.h:40,
                 from /usr/include/c++/11/bits/ios_base.h:41,
                 from /usr/include/c++/11/ios:42,
                 from /usr/include/c++/11/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/11/iostream:39,
                 from /src/test/testing_utilities.h:8,
                 from /src/test/lp_tests.h:8,
                 from /src/test/lp_tests.cpp:5:
/usr/include/stdlib.h:555:13: note: candidate: ‘void free(void*)’
  555 | extern void free (void *__ptr) __THROW;
      |             ^~~~
In file included from /src/third_party/header_only/armadillo-11.1.0/include/armadillo:134,
                 from /src/test/testing_utilities.h:9,
                 from /src/test/lp_tests.h:8,
                 from /src/test/lp_tests.cpp:5:
/src/third_party/header_only/armadillo-11.1.0/include/armadillo_bits/translate_superlu.hpp:341:3: note: candidate: ‘void arma::superlu::free(void*)’
  341 |   free(void* mem)
      |   ^~~~
In file included from /src/third_party/coin-or/CoinUtils/src/CoinModel.hpp:8,
                 from /src/engine/core/../core/lp_interface/lp_osi_interface.h:16,
                 from /src/test/lp_tests.h:13,
                 from /src/test/lp_tests.cpp:5:
/src/third_party/coin-or/CoinUtils/src/CoinModelUseful.hpp:205:11: error: call of overloaded ‘free(char*&)’ is ambiguous
  205 |       free(s->name);
      |       ~~~~^~~~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/c++/11/cstdlib:75,
                 from /usr/include/c++/11/ext/string_conversions.h:41,
                 from /usr/include/c++/11/bits/basic_string.h:6608,
                 from /usr/include/c++/11/string:55,
                 from /usr/include/c++/11/bits/locale_classes.h:40,
                 from /usr/include/c++/11/bits/ios_base.h:41,
                 from /usr/include/c++/11/ios:42,
                 from /usr/include/c++/11/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/11/iostream:39,
                 from /src/test/testing_utilities.h:8,
                 from /src/test/lp_tests.h:8,
                 from /src/test/lp_tests.cpp:5:
/usr/include/stdlib.h:555:13: note: candidate: ‘void free(void*)’
  555 | extern void free (void *__ptr) __THROW;
      |             ^~~~
In file included from /src/third_party/header_only/armadillo-11.1.0/include/armadillo:134,
                 from /src/test/testing_utilities.h:9,
                 from /src/test/lp_tests.h:8,
                 from /src/test/lp_tests.cpp:5:
/src/third_party/header_only/armadillo-11.1.0/include/armadillo_bits/translate_superlu.hpp:341:3: note: candidate: ‘void arma::superlu::free(void*)’
  341 |   free(void* mem)
      |   ^~~~
In file included from /src/third_party/coin-or/CoinUtils/src/CoinModel.hpp:8,
                 from /src/engine/core/../core/lp_interface/lp_osi_interface.h:16,
                 from /src/test/lp_tests.h:13,
                 from /src/test/lp_tests.cpp:5:
/src/third_party/coin-or/CoinUtils/src/CoinModelUseful.hpp:208:11: error: call of overloaded ‘free(symrec*&)’ is ambiguous
  208 |       free(symtable);
      |       ~~~~^~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/c++/11/cstdlib:75,
                 from /usr/include/c++/11/ext/string_conversions.h:41,
                 from /usr/include/c++/11/bits/basic_string.h:6608,
                 from /usr/include/c++/11/string:55,
                 from /usr/include/c++/11/bits/locale_classes.h:40,
                 from /usr/include/c++/11/bits/ios_base.h:41,
                 from /usr/include/c++/11/ios:42,
                 from /usr/include/c++/11/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/11/iostream:39,
                 from /src/test/testing_utilities.h:8,
                 from /src/test/lp_tests.h:8,
                 from /src/test/lp_tests.cpp:5:
/usr/include/stdlib.h:555:13: note: candidate: ‘void free(void*)’
  555 | extern void free (void *__ptr) __THROW;
      |             ^~~~
In file included from /src/third_party/header_only/armadillo-11.1.0/include/armadillo:134,
                 from /src/test/testing_utilities.h:9,
                 from /src/test/lp_tests.h:8,
                 from /src/test/lp_tests.cpp:5:
/src/third_party/header_only/armadillo-11.1.0/include/armadillo_bits/translate_superlu.hpp:341:3: note: candidate: ‘void arma::superlu::free(void*)’
  341 |   free(void* mem)
      |   ^~~~
gmake[3]: *** [CMakeFiles/Tests.dir/build.make:8532: CMakeFiles/Tests.dir/src/test/lp_tests.cpp.o] Error 1
gmake[3]: *** Se espera a que terminen otras tareas....
In file included from /src/third_party/coin-or/Clp/src/ClpModel.hpp:21,
                 from /src/third_party/coin-or/Clp/src/ClpSimplex.hpp:16,
                 from /src/engine/core/../core/lp_interface/lp_osi_interface.h:12,
                 from /src/test/lp_tests.h:13,
                 from /src/test/tests.cpp:20:
/src/third_party/coin-or/CoinUtils/src/CoinHelperFunctions.hpp: In function ‘char* CoinStrdup(const char*)’:
/src/third_party/coin-or/CoinUtils/src/CoinHelperFunctions.hpp:624:39: error: call of overloaded ‘malloc(int)’ is ambiguous
  624 |     dup = static_cast< char * >(malloc(len + 1));
      |                                 ~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/c++/11/cstdlib:75,
                 from /usr/include/c++/11/ext/string_conversions.h:41,
                 from /usr/include/c++/11/bits/basic_string.h:6608,
                 from /usr/include/c++/11/string:55,
                 from /usr/include/c++/11/bits/locale_classes.h:40,
                 from /usr/include/c++/11/bits/ios_base.h:41,
                 from /usr/include/c++/11/ios:42,
                 from /usr/include/c++/11/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/11/iostream:39,
                 from /src/test/tests.cpp:2:
/usr/include/stdlib.h:540:14: note: candidate: ‘void* malloc(size_t)’
  540 | extern void *malloc (size_t __size) __THROW __attribute_malloc__
      |              ^~~~~~
In file included from /src/third_party/header_only/armadillo-11.1.0/include/armadillo:134,
                 from /src/third_party/header_only/mlpack-4.0.0/src/mlpack/core/arma_extend/arma_extend.hpp:21,
                 from /src/third_party/header_only/mlpack-4.0.0/src/mlpack/base.hpp:87,
                 from /src/third_party/header_only/mlpack-4.0.0/src/mlpack.hpp:25,
                 from /src/engine/../utils/type_declarations.h:9,
                 from /src/engine/../utils/armadillo_extension.h:19,
                 from /src/test/../engine/core/data_structures/bus_data.h:10,
                 from /src/test/../engine/core/data_structures/numeric_circuit.h:22,
                 from /src/test/../newton.h:9,
                 from /src/test/tests.cpp:9:
/src/third_party/header_only/armadillo-11.1.0/include/armadillo_bits/translate_superlu.hpp:332:3: note: candidate: ‘void* arma::superlu::malloc(std::size_t)’
  332 |   malloc(size_t N)
      |   ^~~~~~
In file included from /src/third_party/coin-or/CoinUtils/src/CoinModel.hpp:8,
                 from /src/engine/core/../core/lp_interface/lp_osi_interface.h:16,
                 from /src/test/lp_tests.h:13,
                 from /src/test/tests.cpp:20:
/src/third_party/coin-or/CoinUtils/src/CoinModelUseful.hpp: In destructor ‘CoinYacc::~CoinYacc()’:
/src/third_party/coin-or/CoinUtils/src/CoinModelUseful.hpp:200:11: error: call of overloaded ‘free(char*&)’ is ambiguous
  200 |       free(symbuf);
      |       ~~~~^~~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/c++/11/cstdlib:75,
                 from /usr/include/c++/11/ext/string_conversions.h:41,
                 from /usr/include/c++/11/bits/basic_string.h:6608,
                 from /usr/include/c++/11/string:55,
                 from /usr/include/c++/11/bits/locale_classes.h:40,
                 from /usr/include/c++/11/bits/ios_base.h:41,
                 from /usr/include/c++/11/ios:42,
                 from /usr/include/c++/11/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/11/iostream:39,
                 from /src/test/tests.cpp:2:
/usr/include/stdlib.h:555:13: note: candidate: ‘void free(void*)’
  555 | extern void free (void *__ptr) __THROW;
      |             ^~~~
In file included from /src/third_party/header_only/armadillo-11.1.0/include/armadillo:134,
                 from /src/third_party/header_only/mlpack-4.0.0/src/mlpack/core/arma_extend/arma_extend.hpp:21,
                 from /src/third_party/header_only/mlpack-4.0.0/src/mlpack/base.hpp:87,
                 from /src/third_party/header_only/mlpack-4.0.0/src/mlpack.hpp:25,
                 from /src/engine/../utils/type_declarations.h:9,
                 from /src/engine/../utils/armadillo_extension.h:19,
                 from /src/test/../engine/core/data_structures/bus_data.h:10,
                 from /src/test/../engine/core/data_structures/numeric_circuit.h:22,
                 from /src/test/../newton.h:9,
                 from /src/test/tests.cpp:9:
/src/third_party/header_only/armadillo-11.1.0/include/armadillo_bits/translate_superlu.hpp:341:3: note: candidate: ‘void arma::superlu::free(void*)’
  341 |   free(void* mem)
      |   ^~~~
In file included from /src/third_party/coin-or/CoinUtils/src/CoinModel.hpp:8,
                 from /src/engine/core/../core/lp_interface/lp_osi_interface.h:16,
                 from /src/test/lp_tests.h:13,
                 from /src/test/tests.cpp:20:
/src/third_party/coin-or/CoinUtils/src/CoinModelUseful.hpp:205:11: error: call of overloaded ‘free(char*&)’ is ambiguous
  205 |       free(s->name);
      |       ~~~~^~~~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/c++/11/cstdlib:75,
                 from /usr/include/c++/11/ext/string_conversions.h:41,
                 from /usr/include/c++/11/bits/basic_string.h:6608,
                 from /usr/include/c++/11/string:55,
                 from /usr/include/c++/11/bits/locale_classes.h:40,
                 from /usr/include/c++/11/bits/ios_base.h:41,
                 from /usr/include/c++/11/ios:42,
                 from /usr/include/c++/11/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/11/iostream:39,
                 from /src/test/tests.cpp:2:
/usr/include/stdlib.h:555:13: note: candidate: ‘void free(void*)’
  555 | extern void free (void *__ptr) __THROW;
      |             ^~~~
In file included from /src/third_party/header_only/armadillo-11.1.0/include/armadillo:134,
                 from /src/third_party/header_only/mlpack-4.0.0/src/mlpack/core/arma_extend/arma_extend.hpp:21,
                 from /src/third_party/header_only/mlpack-4.0.0/src/mlpack/base.hpp:87,
                 from /src/third_party/header_only/mlpack-4.0.0/src/mlpack.hpp:25,
                 from /src/engine/../utils/type_declarations.h:9,
                 from /src/engine/../utils/armadillo_extension.h:19,
                 from /src/test/../engine/core/data_structures/bus_data.h:10,
                 from /src/test/../engine/core/data_structures/numeric_circuit.h:22,
                 from /src/test/../newton.h:9,
                 from /src/test/tests.cpp:9:
/src/third_party/header_only/armadillo-11.1.0/include/armadillo_bits/translate_superlu.hpp:341:3: note: candidate: ‘void arma::superlu::free(void*)’
  341 |   free(void* mem)
      |   ^~~~
In file included from /src/third_party/coin-or/CoinUtils/src/CoinModel.hpp:8,
                 from /src/engine/core/../core/lp_interface/lp_osi_interface.h:16,
                 from /src/test/lp_tests.h:13,
                 from /src/test/tests.cpp:20:
/src/third_party/coin-or/CoinUtils/src/CoinModelUseful.hpp:208:11: error: call of overloaded ‘free(symrec*&)’ is ambiguous
  208 |       free(symtable);
      |       ~~~~^~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/c++/11/cstdlib:75,
                 from /usr/include/c++/11/ext/string_conversions.h:41,
                 from /usr/include/c++/11/bits/basic_string.h:6608,
                 from /usr/include/c++/11/string:55,
                 from /usr/include/c++/11/bits/locale_classes.h:40,
                 from /usr/include/c++/11/bits/ios_base.h:41,
                 from /usr/include/c++/11/ios:42,
                 from /usr/include/c++/11/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/11/iostream:39,
                 from /src/test/tests.cpp:2:
/usr/include/stdlib.h:555:13: note: candidate: ‘void free(void*)’
  555 | extern void free (void *__ptr) __THROW;
      |             ^~~~
In file included from /src/third_party/header_only/armadillo-11.1.0/include/armadillo:134,
                 from /src/third_party/header_only/mlpack-4.0.0/src/mlpack/core/arma_extend/arma_extend.hpp:21,
                 from /src/third_party/header_only/mlpack-4.0.0/src/mlpack/base.hpp:87,
                 from /src/third_party/header_only/mlpack-4.0.0/src/mlpack.hpp:25,
                 from /src/engine/../utils/type_declarations.h:9,
                 from /src/engine/../utils/armadillo_extension.h:19,
                 from /src/test/../engine/core/data_structures/bus_data.h:10,
                 from /src/test/../engine/core/data_structures/numeric_circuit.h:22,
                 from /src/test/../newton.h:9,
                 from /src/test/tests.cpp:9:
/src/third_party/header_only/armadillo-11.1.0/include/armadillo_bits/translate_superlu.hpp:341:3: note: candidate: ‘void arma::superlu::free(void*)’
  341 |   free(void* mem)
      |   ^~~~
gmake[3]: *** [CMakeFiles/Tests.dir/build.make:8462: CMakeFiles/Tests.dir/src/test/tests.cpp.o] Error 1
gmake[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:324: CMakeFiles/Tests.dir/all] Error 2
gmake[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:331: CMakeFiles/Tests.dir/rule] Error 2
gmake: *** [Makefile:293: Tests] Error 2
```

Comment: Does compiler tell you the candidates for `malloc` it found? It's usually in notes below the error itself.

Comment: Not a solution but a question: why use `malloc` in C++ vs. `new`?

Comment: @Chris Sometimes you want to interface with C, which thinks it might `free()` something you `malloc()`ed.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen I've just update the error, is that it?

Comment: `static_cast<std::size_t>(len + 1)`

Comment: @Eljay `Static_cast from 'void *' to 'std::size_t' (aka 'unsigned long') is not allowed`

Comment: For it to be ambiguous there has to be more than one version of `malloc` to call. Please include the full error message which should include all the versions of the function it finds.

Comment: @Kevin Just edited the question to add it all

Comment: Your last comment implies that `len` is a pointer not an int.

Comment: I have seen such strange behaviours sometimes, too. You can try to include the cstdlib directly from your file.

Comment: What if you use `std::malloc` (or the intruding `arma::superlu::malloc`) instead and drop `using namespace std;` ? Start by removing `using namespace std;` from your header files if you've got it there too. Also remove `using namespace arma::superlu;` and any other `using namespace` you have in your header files

Comment: @TedLyngmo indeed using std::malloc fixes the issues! as it is not my code it was hard to spot the problem

Comment: Search all the header files in the code you've got for `using namespace ...` remove all of those put in the global namespace.

Comment: A header with a global  `using namespace` is a truly nasty surprise. The big take-away from this experience should be "Don't be *that guy*."

Comment: If you are going to resort to using `strlen()` and `malloc()`, then why not just use the standard `strdup()` instead? The documentation for [`CoinStrdup()`](https://www.coin-or.org/Doxygen/CoinUtils/CoinHelperFunctions_8hpp.html#ab432b2f2de9302a35dbb770085e56a06) even says: "***Returns strdup** or NULL if original NULL.*"

Comment: Unrelated to the problem of ambiguous overloads:   converting and storing the return value from `strlen()` as an `int`, and then using it as an argument of `malloc()` offers nothing useful.   `strlen()` returns a `size_t` (more accurately `std::size_t`) and the argument of `malloc()` is also a `size_t`.  Change the type of `len` to be `size_t` and you cleanly eliminate the `static_cast<int>`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The two functions it's considering are the standard `void* malloc(size_t)` and `void* arma::superlu::malloc(std::size_t)`. Presumably somewhere you have `using namespace arma::superlu` which pulls everything from that namespace into the global namespace.

To get around it, you can

1. get rid of `using namespace arma::superlu` and either fully qualify everything from that namespace or pull in exactly you need (with `using arma::superlu::xyz;`). Or
2. Qualify the `malloc` call with `::malloc`, or preferably `std::malloc` to call the C++ standard version.

Similar for the ambiguous calls to `free`.

Answer (score 3):

The error messages explain: the call to `malloc` is ambiguous due to two candidates:

```
std::malloc
arma::superlu::malloc
```

To avoid this you should explicitly call the intended one, e.g. `std::malloc`, rather than relying on overload resolution. You might also want to look at why `arma::superlu::` is being searched. Is there a using directive; or is this code perhaps defined inside that namespace and so that was the intended version of malloc to call.

NB. The code has a vulnerability in the behaviour when the input string is longer than `INT_MAX`,  and it would also be good to check what is going to happen if `malloc` returns a null pointer.

Answer (score 0):

`std::malloc` is **not** a candidate here:

```
/usr/include/stdlib.h:540:14: note: candidate: ‘void* malloc(size_t)’
  540 | extern void *malloc (size_t __size) __THROW __attribute_malloc__
      |              ^~~~~~
...
/src/third_party/header_only/armadillo-11.1.0/include/armadillo_bits/translate_superlu.hpp:332:3: note: candidate: ‘void* arma::superlu::malloc(std::size_t)’
  332 |   malloc(size_t N)
      |   ^~~~~~
```

But the culprit likely is a `using namespace arma::superlu` somewhere in your own code, or in one of the thirdparty headers.